# A connection attempt failed msmq

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, msmq, windows

Need your help for the following issue.

I basically have two applications, one web and another windows application.
The web application is used by the user. After the user provides any service to customer, its entry is made in a table.

I have two private queues configured in MSMQ (InboundQ and OutBoundQ).

My another application viz. a windows application has listener, sender and agents(outward and inward) configured. This application is always running [i.e. the listener, sender, agents are always up].
As the data entry is made in the table, the 'outward agent' monitors it (the table) and sends the message to the OutBoundQ.

The 'sender' continuously monitors the OutBoundQ. As soon as it finds the message in Outbound Queue, it sends it to my application.

The reverse flow also exists, which is working fine.

The messages come in continuously. The two queues, senders, agents, listeners are configured properly. When i start it it works fine. However, after some time it stops. hence, the messages are not processed. I get an error as follows:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ApplicationException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at IC.BusinessComponent.ICSender.SendMessage(String OutBoundMessage)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IC.BusinessComponent.ICSender.SendMessage(String OutBoundMessage)
   at IC.Interface.FrmISHSender.ReceiveMessage()
   at IC.Interface.FrmISHSender.RecvMsgTicker_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

However, when we restart it it starts working fine and then again stops.

This application has been working properly for over 6-8 years. There has never been such issue. Also, there has been no code changes in past one year.

They recently moved application to another server.
What could be the issue? I am completely unaware about this scenario.

The client is facing continuous piling up of messages and the one that are getting processed is also slow.

Please help.